# How to make print invisible (web creating)?

Tags: python, html

I'm making a movie website for my assignment, but I've been given codes I haven't learnt yet.

I'm using 3 files so I can utilize my learning in class objects.

I have a problem in one of them. (shown below).

I use this code to go through and process all the details (arguments) for the movies I've set up.
I've set up my arguments `=None`, because some of my movies I've listed to go through the process has less than the required argument in the function. i.e. in the html file, it causes the text to print 'None'.

```
import webbrowser

# Uses class method to organise movie contents.
#INPUT (1)title, (2)description, (3)poster image url, (4)youtube trailer, (5)running time/duration (6)number of season, (7)number of episode, (8)tv station
#all arguments uses string elements.
class Movie():
    """This class provides a way to store movie and tv shows related information"""
    def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image, trailer_youtube, duration_time=None, number_of_seasons=None, tv_station=None):
        self.title = movie_title
        self.storyline = movie_storyline
        self.poster_image_url = poster_image
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube
#        blank = ' '
#        if duration_time == True:
#            return blank
#        else:
        self.duration = duration_time
        self.seasons = number_of_seasons
        self.station = tv_station

    def show_trailer(self):
        """Opens Trailer in webbrowser"""
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)
```

Here's a screenshot of it - I've highlighted where it print out the text 'None'. 
[image]

How can I change to text to give a nothing at all instead of having the text 'None'.

**html code via python**
This is in a different file, note.

```
import webbrowser
import os
import re
print ""
#ready html tags ->  use following code
#print("Content-Type: text/HTML")

# Styles and scripting for the page
main_page_head = '''
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fresh Tomatoes!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            padding-top: 80px;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        #trailer .modal-dialog {
            margin-top: 200px;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
        }
        .hanging-close {
            position: absolute;
            top: -12px;
            right: -12px;
            z-index: 9001;
        }
        #trailer-video {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .movie-tile {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .movie-tile:hover {
            background-color: #d1d1d1;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .scale-media {
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .scale-media iframe {
            border: none;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Pause the video when the modal is closed
        $(document).on('click', '.hanging-close, .modal-backdrop, .modal', function (event) {
            // Remove the src so the player itself gets removed, as this is the only
            // reliable way to ensure the video stops playing in IE
            $("#trailer-video-container").empty();
        });
        // Start playing the video whenever the trailer modal is opened
        $(document).on('click', '.movie-tile', function (event) {
            var trailerYouTubeId = $(this).attr('data-trailer-youtube-id')
            var sourceUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + trailerYouTubeId + '?autoplay=1&html5=1';
            $("#trailer-video-container").empty().append($("<iframe></iframe>", {
              'id': 'trailer-video',
              'type': 'text-html',
              'src': sourceUrl,
              'frameborder': 0
            }));
        });
        // Animate in the movies when the page loads
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.movie-tile').hide().first().show("fast", function showNext() {
            $(this).next("div").show("fast", showNext);
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
'''

# The main page layout and title bar
main_page_content = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <!-- Trailer Video Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="trailer">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <a href="#" class="hanging-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <img src=""/>
          </a>
          <div class="scale-media" id="trailer-video-container">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Find your Favourite Movies</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      {movie_tiles}
    </div>
    <footer style='text-align: center;'><em>A Udacity project</em></footer>
  </body>
</html>
'''

# A single movie entry html template
movie_tile_content = '''
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="{trailer_youtube_id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
    <img src="{poster_image_url}" width="220" height="342">
    <h2>{movie_title}</h2>
    alt="" title="hover text"<p>{movie_storyline}<p>
    <p>{duration_time} {number_of_seasons}</p>
    <p>{tv_station}</p>
</div>
'''

def create_movie_tiles_content(movies):
    # The HTML content for this section of the page
    content = ''
    for movie in movies:
        # Extract the youtube ID from the url
        youtube_id_match = re.search(r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
        youtube_id_match = youtube_id_match or re.search(r'(?<=be/)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
        trailer_youtube_id = youtube_id_match.group(0) if youtube_id_match else None

        # Append the tile for the movie with its content filled in
        content += movie_tile_content.format(
            movie_title=movie.title,
            poster_image_url=movie.poster_image_url,
            trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id,
            movie_storyline=movie.storyline,
            duration_time=movie.duration,
            number_of_seasons=movie.seasons,
            tv_station=movie.station
        )
    return content

def open_movies_page(movies):
  # Create or overwrite the output file
  output_file = open('fresh_tomatoes.html', 'w')

  # Replace the placeholder for the movie tiles with the actual dynamically generated content
  rendered_content = main_page_content.format(movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))

  # Output the file
  output_file.write(main_page_head + rendered_content)
  output_file.close()

  # open the output file in the browser
  url = os.path.abspath(output_file.name)
  webbrowser.open('file://' + url, new=2) # open in a new tab, if possible
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your HTML file.

Comment: You're passing through 'None' as the default, when the given parameter isn't specified. Simply remove the default 'None' logic by using something like `''` instead, or better yet, run a condition for when the parameter isn't specified where you only output the content when it *is* specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution is to pass an empty string `''` instead of `None`. In Python, an empty string evaluates to "falsey" anyways, so the two are similar. The only difference is an empty string will print as blank.

```
def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image, trailer_youtube, duration_time='', number_of_seasons='', tv_station=''):
```

The other option is to add some logic to your HTML template. You didn't include your HTML in the question so consider this pseudo-code.

```
{% if number_of_seasons %}
    <div class="seasons">{{ number_of_seasons }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The html code is given to me for the project and some Javascript and other languages are there I haven't learnt yet. But I do know a good amount of html and little of python.